# ansible - create new variable based on the output of register variable

Tags: ansible

I am hoping that anyone could help me. I am new to ansible, and I've been searching for solutions for the last few days but no luck. I wanted to create a variable based on the output of the register variable in tasks.

Below is the variables I used:

```
ports:
 access:
 - int:
   - "Ethernet1/0"
   - "Ethernet1/1"
   voice: 10
   data: 100
 - int:
   - "Ethernet2/0"
   - "Ethernet2/1"
   voice: 11
   data: 101
 trunk:
 - int:
   - "Ethernet0/0"
   - "Ethernet0/1"
   allowed_vlans: "10,100,11,101"
   range: "range e0/0 - 1"
```

---

```
- name: show interface swicthport
  ios_command:
    provider: "{{ provider }}"
    commands:
    - show interface {{ item.1 }} switchport
  register: show_out
  with_subelements:
  - "{{ ports.trunk }}"
  - int
- debug: var=show
```

Below is the output from debug:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [acc_sw_01] => {
"show_out": {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "All items completed", 
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "_ansible_parsed": true, 
            "changed": false, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "auth_pass": null, 
                    "authorize": false, 
                    "commands": [
                        "show interface Ethernet0/0 switchport"
                    ], 
                    "host": "acc_sw_01", 
                    "interval": 1, 
                    "match": "all", 
                    "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                    "port": null, 
                    "provider": {
                        "host": "acc_sw_01", 
                        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                        "transport": "cli", 
                        "username": "rey"
                    }, 
                    "retries": 10, 
                    "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                    "timeout": 10, 
                    "transport": "cli", 
                    "use_ssl": true, 
                    "username": "rey", 
                    "validate_certs": true, 
                    "wait_for": null
                }, 
                "module_name": "ios_command"
            }, 
            "item": [
                {
                    "allowed_vlans": "10,100,500", 
                    "range": "range e0/0 - 1"
                }, 
                "Ethernet0/0"
            ], 
            "stdout": [
                "Name: Et0/0\nSwitchport: Enabled\nAdministrative Mode: dynamic auto\nOperational Mode: down\nAdministrative Trunking Encapsulation: negotiate\nNegotiation of Trunking: On\nAccess Mode VLAN: 1 (default)\nTrunking Native Mode VLAN: 1 (default)\nAdministrative Native VLAN tagging: enabled\nVoice VLAN: none\nAdministrative private-vlan host-association: none \nAdministrative private-vlan mapping: none \nAdministrative private-vlan trunk native VLAN: none\nAdministrative private-vlan trunk Native VLAN tagging: enabled\nAdministrative private-vlan trunk encapsulation: dot1q\nAdministrative private-vlan trunk normal VLANs: none\nAdministrative private-vlan trunk associations: none\nAdministrative private-vlan trunk mappings: none\nOperational private-vlan: none\nTrunking VLANs Enabled: ALL\nPruning VLANs Enabled: 2-1001\nCapture Mode Disabled\nCapture VLANs Allowed: ALL\n\nProtected: false\nAppliance trust: none"
            ], 
            "stdout_lines": [
                [
                    "Name: Et0/0", 
                    "Switchport: Enabled", 
                    "Administrative Mode: dynamic auto", 
                    "Operational Mode: down", 
                    "Administrative Trunking Encapsulation: negotiate", 
                    "Negotiation of Trunking: On", 
                    "Access Mode VLAN: 1 (default)", 
                    "Trunking Native Mode VLAN: 1 (default)", 
                    "Administrative Native VLAN tagging: enabled", 
                    "Voice VLAN: none", 
                    "Administrative private-vlan host-association: none ", 
                    "Administrative private-vlan mapping: none ", 
                    "Administrative private-vlan trunk native VLAN: none", 
                    "Administrative private-vlan trunk Native VLAN tagging: enabled", 
                    "Administrative private-vlan trunk encapsulation: dot1q", 
                    "Administrative private-vlan trunk normal VLANs: none", 
                    "Administrative private-vlan trunk associations: none", 
                    "Administrative private-vlan trunk mappings: none", 
                    "Operational private-vlan: none", 
                    "Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL", 
                    "Pruning VLANs Enabled: 2-1001", 
                    "Capture Mode Disabled", 
                    "Capture VLANs Allowed: ALL", 
                    "", 
                    "Protected: false", 
                    "Appliance trust: none"
                ]
            ], 
            "warnings": []
        },
```

Based on the output, how can I set a variable with a value "Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL"?

Thanks in advance and I appreciate any response

**EDIT:**
@Konstantin I appreciate your help and patience. Your answer was right, is just that my question is not clear, you are also right regarding the with_subelements no need to use it. I edit the task below.

```
- name: show interface swicthport
  ios_command:
    provider: "{{ provider }}"
    commands:
    - show interface switchport | include Name|Trunking VLANs Enabled
  register: show_out
```

Debug output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [acc_sw_01] => {
"show_out": {
    "changed": false, 
    "stdout": [
        "Name: Et0/0\nTrunking VLANs Enabled: 11\nName: Et0/1\nTrunking VLANs Enabled: ALL"
    ], 
    "stdout_lines": [
        [
            "Name: Et0/0", 
            "Trunking VLANs Enabled: 11", 
            "Name: Et0/1", 
            "Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL", 
        ]
    ], 
    "warnings": []
  }
}
```

How am I able to create a list of dictionaries or hashes based on the output? something like:

```
- name: "Et0/0"
  trunkning_vlans_enabled:11
- name: "Et0/1"
  trunking_vlans_enabled: all

  or     

  Eth0/0:
    trunking_vlans_enable: 11
  Eth0/1:
    trunkning_vlans_enable: all
```

Thanks

Comment: Provided output is definitely truncated (it should have `results`, `items`, etc.). And please rephrase your question: do you need to get specific interface which has thie specific line in its config?

Comment: In your example `show_out.results` is a list with possibly multiple interfaces described. What line do you want in that case?

Comment: Hi Konstantin,
Sorry I deleted the previous comment that was incomplete but anyway I wanted the line with "Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL", thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple interfaces? or just one (what is the reason for `with_subelements` in this case)?

Comment: Hi Konstantin, sorry for late reply. Yes, I have multiple interfaces. The with_subelemets is where all the interfaces listed, it's a variable under host_vars. Basically the tasks just show the switchport configuration of all the interface in the variable. Thanks

Comment: I edit the question above to include the variable I use in this case,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want, but you can start with this example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    show_out:
      results:
        - item: Ethernet0/0
          stdout_lines: [
                [
                    "Name: Et0/0",
                    "Switchport: Enabled",
                    "Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL",
                    "Appliance trust: none"
                ]
            ]
        - item: Ethernet0/1
          stdout_lines: [
                [
                    "Name: Et0/1",
                    "Switchport: Enabled",
                    "Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL",
                    "Appliance trust: none"
                ]
            ]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ show_out.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | map('first') | map('intersect',['Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL']) | list }}"
```